# Rails admin hide buttons in has_many nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, has-many, rails-admin, belongs-to

I am using Rails Admin. I have three models:

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :tags_users, :dependent => :destroy  
end

class TagsUser < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user_spot, :inverse_of => :tags_users
    belongs_to :tag
end

class UserSpot < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :tags_users, :inverse_of => :user_spot
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :tags_users, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

and what's being displayed:

[image]

I would like to hide the buttons "**Add a new tag**" and "**Edit this tag**". How could I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
field :tag do 
  inline_add false
  inline_edit false
end
```

Comment: I added it in config.model TagsUser in initializers/rails_admin.rb and it worked. Thanks!